# Ban list for HTML Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a modal window with five selects on it

```
<h4>Amenities</h4>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Amenities)
<br />

<div id="editPrioritiesModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Set the priority to the items and then apply the desired changes</h5>

        <div><select id="AmenityDropDownP1" data-previous-value="" onfocus="updatePrevious(this);" onchange="refreshBans(this); this.oldvalue = this.value;"></select></div>
        <div><select id="AmenityDropDownP2" data-previous-value="" onfocus="updatePrevious(this);" onchange="    refreshBans(this); this.oldvalue = this.value;"></select></div>
        <div><select id="AmenityDropDownP3" data-previous-value="" onfocus="updatePrevious(this);" onchange="    refreshBans(this); this.oldvalue = this.value;"></select></div>
        <div><select id="AmenityDropDownP4" data-previous-value="" onfocus="updatePrevious(this);" onchange="    refreshBans(this); this.oldvalue = this.value;"></select></div>
        <div><select id="AmenityDropDownP5" data-previous-value="" onfocus="updatePrevious(this);" onchange="    refreshBans(this); this.oldvalue = this.value;"></select></div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="reveretPrioritiesButton" onclick=" revertValues()">Revert</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="savePriorityButton" onclick="applyModalValues()">Save Changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This modal window is used to edit multiple priority sets, the corresponding "Sets" are rendered as follows:

```
@{
    var featuresList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.SelectedFeatures);
}

<script>
    function initializeFeaturesList(featuresList) {
        window.availableFeaturesList = featuresList;
    }

    initializeFeaturesList(@Html.Raw(featuresList));
</script>

@{
    if (Model.AmenityPriorityConfigs != null)
    {
        <h4>Prioritisations</h4>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="amenitiesPrioritiesTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                    <th>P1</th>
                    <th>P2</th>
                    <th>P3</th>
                    <th>P4</th>
                    <th>P5</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            @{
        int trNum = 0;

        foreach (var apcViewModel in Model.AmenityPriorityConfigs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@apcViewModel.Product.Name</td>
                <td class="AmenityP1">@(apcViewModel.AmenityP1 != null ? apcViewModel.AmenityP1.Name : string.Empty)</td>
                <td class="AmenityP2">@(apcViewModel.AmenityP2 != null ? apcViewModel.AmenityP2.Name : string.Empty)</td>
                <td class="AmenityP3">@(apcViewModel.AmenityP3 != null ? apcViewModel.AmenityP3.Name : string.Empty)</td>
                <td class="AmenityP4">@(apcViewModel.AmenityP4 != null ? apcViewModel.AmenityP4.Name : string.Empty)</td>
                <td class="AmenityP5">@(apcViewModel.AmenityP5 != null ? apcViewModel.AmenityP5.Name : string.Empty)</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="amenitiesModalLink" data-toggle="modal" data-amenity-configuration-id="@apcViewModel.Id" onclick="showEditModal(@Model.Id, @apcViewModel.Product.Id, '@apcViewModel.Product.Name', this, @featuresList)">
                        <i class="icon-edit" title="Delete"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            trNum++;
        }
            }

        </table>
    }
}
```

And in the following JS you can see that all the dropdowns are populated during modal opening:

```
var targetCentreId;
var targetProductId;
var targetConfigurationId;
var targetRow;
var availableFeaturesList;

$(function() {
    var previous;

    $("#editPrioritiesModal select").on('focus', function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function () {
        // Do something with the previous value after the change
        alert(previous);

        // Make sure the previous value is updated
        previous = this.value;
    });
});

function showEditModal(centreId, productId, productName, initiator) {

    initGlobals(centreId, productId, initiator);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var targetDropDown = $('#AmenityDropDownP' + (i + 1));

        populateDropDown(targetDropDown);
        updateDropdown(i, targetDropDown);
    }

    $('#editPrioritiesModal').modal('show');
}

function populateDropDown(targetDropDown) {
    $(targetDropDown).empty();
    var emptyOption = '';
    emptyOption += '<option value="null"></option>';
    $(targetDropDown).append(emptyOption);

    for (var j = 0; j < availableFeaturesList.length; j++) {
        var option = '';
        option += '<option value="' + availableFeaturesList[j].Id + '">' + availableFeaturesList[j].Name + '</option>';
        $(targetDropDown).append(option);
    }
}

function initGlobals(centreId, productId, initiator) {
    targetCentreId = centreId;
    targetProductId = productId;
    targetConfigurationId = $(initiator).data('amenity-configuration-id');
    targetRow = $(initiator).closest('tr');
}

function revertValues() {
    if (targetConfigurationId == 0) {
        $('#editPrioritiesModal select').each(function () {
            this.selectedIndex = 0;
        });

        targetRow.find('td').filter(function () {
            return this.className.match(/(AmenityP)(\d)/i);
        }).each(function () {
            this.innerText = '';
        });

    } else {
        getAmenityConfiguration(updateRowAndAllDropdowns);
    }
}

function applyModalValues() {
    MessageBox.AddLoader();

    //save => i need centreId, after saving i should rewrite the state of the table INCLUDING THE OPEN DROPDOWN LINK (item Id)
    var p1Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP1').val();
    var p2Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP2').val();
    var p3Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP3').val();
    var p4Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP4').val();
    var p5Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP5').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/centre/SaveAmenityPriotyConfiguration',
        data:
        {
            'configurationId': targetConfigurationId,
            'centreId': targetCentreId,
            'productId': targetProductId,
            'amenityP1Id': p1Value,
            'amenityP2Id': p2Value,
            'amenityP3Id': p3Value,
            'amenityP4Id': p4Value,
            'amenityP5Id': p5Value,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                updateRowAndAllDropdowns(data);
                updateModalLink(data.Id);
                MessageBox.AddInfo("Success!");
                $('#editPrioritiesModal').modal('hide');

            } else {
                alert("No such entity");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            MessageBox.AddError("Server Error. " + req + " " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

function updateDropdown(amenityIndex, targetDropDown) {
    var probableDataSource = $(targetRow).find('.AmenityP' + (amenityIndex + 1));

    if (probableDataSource.text() !== '') {
        $(targetDropDown).find("option").each(function () {
            var currText = $(this).text();

            if (currText === probableDataSource.text()) {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(targetDropDown).prop('selectedIndex', -1);
    }
}

function updateRow(model) {
    targetRow.find('td').filter(function () {
        return this.className.match(/(AmenityP)(\d)/i);
    }).each(function () {
        this.innerText = model[this.className].Name;
    });
}

function updateRowAndAllDropdowns(model) {
    updateRow(model);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var targetDropDown = $('#AmenityDropDownP' + (i + 1));
        updateDropdown(i, targetDropDown);
    }
}

function getAmenityConfiguration(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/centre/GetAmenityPriorityConfiguration',
        data: { 'configurationId': targetConfigurationId },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                successCallback(data);

            } else {
                alert("No such entity");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            MessageBox.AddError("Server Error. " + req + " " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

function updateModalLink(newItemId) {
    $(targetRow).find('a.amenitiesModalLink').first().data('amenity-configuration-id', newItemId);
}

function updateFeaturesList(checkboxItem) {
    var $checkboxItem = $(checkboxItem),
        featureId = $checkboxItem.data("id"),
        featureName = $checkboxItem.data("feature-name"),
        isChecked = $checkboxItem.is(":checked"),
        isPresentInList = false;

    var indexOfElement;

    for (var i in availableFeaturesList) {
        if (availableFeaturesList[i].Id == featureId) {
            isPresentInList = true;
            indexOfElement = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isChecked && !isPresentInList) {
        availableFeaturesList.push({ Id: featureId, Name: featureName });

        availableFeaturesList.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.Name < b.Name)
                return -1;
            if (a.Name > b.Name)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

    else if (!isChecked && isPresentInList) {
        availableFeaturesList.splice(indexOfElement, 1);
    }
}

function refreshBans(element) {
    alert(element.data("previous-value"));
    alert(element.value);
}

function updatePrevious(element) {
    element.data("previous-value", element.value);
}
```

The problem: it should be possible to select one dropdown option for each particular "priority set" only once (no duplicates in different dropdowns of one set), so I assume there should be something like a ban-list, that is filled with newly selected option of any dropdown and removes it from all the other ones, or there is another, more graceful solution? Thank you in advance for any advices/critics, I'm a JavaScript novice...
**Upd.**
One more detail, some of the dropdowns are getting particular options selected during the work of `showEditModal` function based on the values of the `amenitiesPrioritiesTable` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working script, pay attention to `.change` event and `populateDropDownFromSource`:

```
var targetCentreId;
var targetProductId;
var targetConfigurationId;
var targetRow;
var availableFeaturesList;

$(function () {
    $("#editPrioritiesModal select").change(function () {

        var selectedElems = $("#editPrioritiesModal select").map(function () {
            return parseInt($(this).val());
        }).get();
        $("#editPrioritiesModal select").not(this).each(function () {
            var currVal = parseInt($(this).val());
            populateDropDownFromSource(this, selectedElems);
            $(this).val(currVal);
        });
    });
});

function showEditModal(centreId, productId, productName, initiator) {

    initGlobals(centreId, productId, initiator);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var targetDropDown = $('#AmenityDropDownP' + (i + 1));

        populateDropDown(targetDropDown);
        updateDropdown(i, targetDropDown);
    }

    $('#AmenityDropDownP1').trigger("change");//it's a hack, but is a simplest way to do it

    $('#editPrioritiesModal').modal('show');
}

function populateDropDown(targetDropDown) {
    $(targetDropDown).empty();
    var emptyOption = '';
    emptyOption += '<option value="null"></option>';
    $(targetDropDown).append(emptyOption);

    for (var j = 0; j < availableFeaturesList.length; j++) {
        var option = '';
        option += '<option value="' + availableFeaturesList[j].Id + '">' + availableFeaturesList[j].Name + '</option>';
        $(targetDropDown).append(option);
    }
}

function populateDropDownFromSource(targetDropDown, selectedElems) {
    var currentValue = parseInt($(targetDropDown).val());
    var notSelectedFeatures = $.grep(availableFeaturesList, function (e) {
        return selectedElems.indexOf(e.Id) == -1 || e.Id == currentValue;
    });

    $(targetDropDown).empty();
    var emptyOption = '';
    emptyOption += '<option value="null"></option>';
    $(targetDropDown).append(emptyOption);

    for (var j = 0; j < notSelectedFeatures.length; j++) {
        var option = '';
        option += '<option value="' + notSelectedFeatures[j].Id + '">' + notSelectedFeatures[j].Name + '</option>';
        $(targetDropDown).append(option);
    }
}


function initGlobals(centreId, productId, initiator) {
    targetCentreId = centreId;
    targetProductId = productId;
    targetConfigurationId = $(initiator).data('amenity-configuration-id');
    targetRow = $(initiator).closest('tr');
}

function revertValues() {
    if (targetConfigurationId == 0) {
        $('#editPrioritiesModal select').each(function () {
            this.selectedIndex = 0;
        });

        targetRow.find('td').filter(function () {
            return this.className.match(/(AmenityP)(\d)/i);
        }).each(function () {
            this.innerText = '';
        });

    } else {
        getAmenityConfiguration(updateRowAndAllDropdowns);
    }
}

function applyModalValues() {
    MessageBox.AddLoader();

    //save => i need centreId, after saving i should rewrite the state of the table INCLUDING THE OPEN DROPDOWN LINK (item Id)
    var p1Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP1').val();
    var p2Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP2').val();
    var p3Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP3').val();
    var p4Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP4').val();
    var p5Value = $('#AmenityDropDownP5').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/centre/SaveAmenityPriotyConfiguration',
        data:
        {
            'configurationId': targetConfigurationId,
            'centreId': targetCentreId,
            'productId': targetProductId,
            'amenityP1Id': p1Value,
            'amenityP2Id': p2Value,
            'amenityP3Id': p3Value,
            'amenityP4Id': p4Value,
            'amenityP5Id': p5Value,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                updateRowAndAllDropdowns(data);
                updateModalLink(data.Id);
                MessageBox.AddInfo("Success!");
                $('#editPrioritiesModal').modal('hide');

            } else {
                alert("No such entity");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            MessageBox.AddError("Server Error. " + req + " " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

function updateDropdown(amenityIndex, targetDropDown) {
    var probableDataSource = $(targetRow).find('.AmenityP' + (amenityIndex + 1));

    if (probableDataSource.text() !== '') {
        $(targetDropDown).find("option").each(function () {
            var currText = $(this).text();

            if (currText === probableDataSource.text()) {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(targetDropDown).prop('selectedIndex', -1);
    }
}

function updateRow(model) {
    targetRow.find('td').filter(function () {
        return this.className.match(/(AmenityP)(\d)/i);
    }).each(function () {
        this.innerText = model[this.className].Name;
    });
}

function updateRowAndAllDropdowns(model) {
    updateRow(model);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var targetDropDown = $('#AmenityDropDownP' + (i + 1));
        updateDropdown(i, targetDropDown);
    }
}

function getAmenityConfiguration(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/centre/GetAmenityPriorityConfiguration',
        data: { 'configurationId': targetConfigurationId },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                successCallback(data);

            } else {
                alert("No such entity");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            MessageBox.AddError("Server Error. " + req + " " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

function updateModalLink(newItemId) {
    $(targetRow).find('a.amenitiesModalLink').first().data('amenity-configuration-id', newItemId);
}

function updateFeaturesList(checkboxItem) {
    var $checkboxItem = $(checkboxItem),
        featureId = $checkboxItem.data("id"),
        featureName = $checkboxItem.data("feature-name"),
        isChecked = $checkboxItem.is(":checked"),
        isPresentInList = false;

    var indexOfElement;

    for (var i in availableFeaturesList) {
        if (availableFeaturesList[i].Id == featureId) {
            isPresentInList = true;
            indexOfElement = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isChecked && !isPresentInList) {
        availableFeaturesList.push({ Id: featureId, Name: featureName });

        availableFeaturesList.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.Name < b.Name)
                return -1;
            if (a.Name > b.Name)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

    else if (!isChecked && isPresentInList) {
        availableFeaturesList.splice(indexOfElement, 1);
    }
}

function refreshBans(element) {
    alert(element.data("previous-value"));
    alert(element.value);
}

function updatePrevious(element) {
    element.data("previous-value", element.value);
}
```